# D I - Method or Tabulator method collapses at $\sin^2(x)$ - why is that?

Tags: integration

I have  recently learned about the [tabulator or D-I Method](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2I-_SV8cwsw).

This method - as far as I got it right - is just a variation of integration by parts. It works out very well, even in cases where you get a repetition in one line. But for $\int \sin^2(x) \ dx$ it doesn't work out and ends in $0=0$.  I tried to do it several times, checked each step and it doesn't work out.

Why is that?

Edit:

Calculations (this is the same as when using the DI-Method):

$$\int sin²(x) \\= -sin(x)*cos(x) - \int cos(x)*cos(x) \\=-sin(x)*cos(x)+cos(x)*sin(x) + \int cos(x)*sin(x) $$ at this spot you can see that each part is canceling out each other.

Comment: Integration by parts works just fine on sine squared? Compare your calculations with this for instance: https://socratic.org/questions/how-do-you-integrate-int-sin-2x-by-integration-by-parts-method

Comment: It would help if you posted your calculations here, tracking down your error would be a doable task then

Comment: When using integration by parts you are actually using the identity of $$cos²(x)=1-sin^2(x)$$ If you don't use this and keep continuing you end up with the same loop. Is it necessary to use that identity ?

Comment: @LurioTabasco there might be some other trig equality that does the job; but you can not further simplify just by integrating by parts over and over again

Comment: Why not use: $2\sin^2 x = 1-\cos(2x)$?